# Inverse Laplace Transform of $s^{-2}(s^2 + 1)^{-1}$ Using Convolution Theorem?

Tags: laplace-transform, convolution

I am trying to find the inverse Laplace transform of $s^{-2}(s^2 + 1)^{-1}$. I could multiply these together and use partial fraction decomposition, but, unless I am mistaken, I think there is another way by using the convolution theorem?

I would greatly appreciate it if someone could please take the time to demonstrate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F(s) = s^{-2}(s^2 + 1)^{-1}$ and let $\mathcal{L}(f(t)) = F(s)$
We know that 
$$\mathcal{L}(t) = s^{-2}$$
and
$$\mathcal{L}(\sin t) = (s^2 + 1)^{-1}$$
So
$$F(s) = \mathcal{L} (f(t) )= \mathcal{L}( t * \sin t) = \mathcal{L}( t )\mathcal{L}( \sin t)  = s^{-2}(s^2 + 1)^{-1}$$
where $*$ stands for convolution.
So, the time domain laplace inverse is really
$$f(t) = t * \sin t = \int\limits_0^t \tau \sin(t - \tau) \ d \tau= \int\limits_0^t (t - \tau) \sin(\tau) \ d \tau = t - \sin (t)$$

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. The convolution theorem gives you the inverse Laplace Transform of $ s^{-2}(s^2+1)^{-1}$ as a convolution

$t*\sin t$

The convolution integral is $\int _0^t \tau \sin (t-\tau )d\tau $ which is easy to evaluate.